# How to keep 2 digits after decimal in a float through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a number as 0.233333333333

I want it to show 0.23 instead.
I know the function named toFixed() for that purpose.
I don't find the exact html element to add a event handler.
I want to manipulate the Dom with jQuery/javascript so that the toFixed function pass through the 0.23333333333 string and return it as 0.23 .

Thanks.
I hope I made myself clear.

Comment: Can you show the code? That helps us to help you.

Comment: _"I hope I made myself clear."_ - No, not really. Where does the number come from? Where do you want to "return it"? Please show some of your code...

Comment: Yap. Sure. It's an Wp Woocommerce site. Here's the Url to show you what I want. http://devhj.linkinguplocal.com/product/action-aire-compact-adjustable-folding-fan/ . I want to manipulate the element 0.2323232323 to show as 0.23 .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, from the website you linked to it seems the value is in a particular element as follows:

```
<del>$0.23333333333333</del>
```

You can fix that formatting in several ways, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $("del").text(function(i, t) {
        return "$" + (+t.slice(1)).toFixed(2);
    });    
});
```

That is, skip the dollar sign by taking the current text from the second character onwards with `.slice(1)`, then use the unary plus operator to convert that to a number so that you can use `.toFixed(2)`, then concatenate that back after a dollar sign.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u5Qmv/

Or use a regex `.replace()` to just keep the part you want:

```
        return t.replace(/(\$\d+\.\d\d).*/, "$1");
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u5Qmv/1/

Or `.slice()` from the start of the string through to two characters after the index of the `.` (if there's a possibility there will be no `.` you need to test for it and only `.slice()` if there is one - I'll leave that to you):

```
        return t.slice(0, t.indexOf('.') + 3);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/u5Qmv/2/

Having said all of that, you're better off doing this server-side.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know The server side would be the best part. but My client doesn't have the time I think It'd take me to figure out the fixes. Ok. I want to display everything including the dollar sign as well. I believe it'll help me.

Answer (score 2):

```
parseFloat(parseFloat("0.233333333333").toPrecision(2))
```

You can use the .html() function in jQuery to set or get values of a DOM element - http://api.jquery.com/html/

```
$(selector).html(parseFloat(parseFloat("0.233333333333").toPrecision(2)))
```

Comment: Why the double parseFloat? I think OP only wants to display it, not use it for calculation.

Comment: Question is not very clear, if he wants to only display then I will edit it

Comment: I think so, not sure.

Comment: I know the toFixed function does the job. but the primary concern is how to select the html from the outside of the DOM. In jquery have a selector but doesn't have a method like the toFixed or toPrecision.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Better, you do it on server side if you serving html files. If your site is a single page application, you can do it on template rendering.

Worst case, you do it in jQuery ready

```
 $(function() { 
    // search for elements which contains value, iterate them and update the element
 }
```